# INNER JOIN with subquery with max and where clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT a.ts, b.barcodenumber, a.remarks, c.department 
FROM documentlog a 
INNER JOIN (select docid, max(logid) as logid from documentlog GROUP BY docid) d ON d.docid=a.docid AND d.logid=a.logid 
INNER JOIN user c ON c.uid=a.user 
INNER JOIN document b ON b.id=a.docid
WHERE c.department = 'PTO' AND b.end = 0
```

My problem is When I execute this query it's slow like 2sec+ execution but the data is only 9 , How can I speed up the execution of my query?

[Old SS for EXPLAIN RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Go6t.png)

[UPDATED SS for EXPLAIN RESULT (Add INDEX logid,docid)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kcqr.png)

Comment: Can you try to avoid the subquery in your second line? Most probably that's the main cause.

Comment: Also check your indexing on the fields you are joining with, and c.department

Comment: How large are these tables?  Are you using MySQL 8+ or later?  What is the `EXPLAIN` plan?

Comment: [This](https://atech.blog/viaduct/mysql-indexes-primer) might be of help.

Comment: To avoid the subquery, try to get the var before : `SET @docid = (SELECT docid...); SET @max_logid = (SELECT @max(logid)...);` and then do your INNER JOIN on those value maybe?

Comment: @OliverMGrech how can I avoid my subquery? can you suggest a way to do it? I'm sorry but i'm not good enough to know the way, But I will study it. and 1 thing, do I need to index the `department` column?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Hi, where do I set that var? and can you please tell some more explanation , then I will study.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen update the SS for EXPLAIN result

Comment: @MickaelLeger I'm trying this `SET @maxlogid = (SELECT max(logid) as logid from documentlog GROUP BY docid); ` but I got this error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row, how can I write that variable that will handle my subquery?

Comment: @koroku, Please keep the old Explain output alongside the updated Explain output for reference purposes.

Comment: @ultrajohn sorry for the late reply, I edit again my post question. 
for update, still slow execution

Comment: @koroku : if you use `SET @var = (SELECT...)` you need to return ONE result. If you have more result, you need to use a cursor to select multiple row then loop through them, but no idea if it's faster for you...

Comment: I would index the department column, yes, though not sure how huge your data/resultset is

Comment: @OliverMGrech I already INDEX department column, but still slow execution happen, hmm. any idea?

Comment: ultrajohn has the details for you in an answer below, check it out. and make sure you mark/voteup to answers or comments that you might find helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your EXPLAIN result. Notice that MySQL does not use any kind of key when querying the `documentlog` table i.e., the `documentlog` table does not have a key defined on it. More than 2 million records are processed at this point in your query. This could be the most likely source of the slowness of your query.

Add an index on the `docid`, and `logid` fields in your `documentlog` table and check if it improves the queries' execution time.

**Update!!**

The output of the updated `EXPLAIN` query is saying that it is using a **full table scan!!** (i.e., `type=ALL`) to produce the output of the main outer query. Why? This is caused by the fact that there are no indices defined on the attributes used in the `Where` clause i.e., (`department` and `end`).

In general, if you want to speed up queries, then one has to make sure that appropriate indices are defined for the attributes used in the queries' `WHERE` condition.

By the way, you can learn more about the meaning of MySQL's EXPLAIN result by reading its [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: I already add INDEX for docid, then in logid I set it as PRIMARY KEY do I need to set again to INDEX ? or not? I'll update my SS for EXPLAIN result

Comment: Hi, when I add `logid` INDEX then the execution is improve a little, but when I change the condition `WHERE` to more character e.g. `WHERE c.department='ACCOUNTING` execution is fast, then when I change `c.department='PICTO' ` execution become slow. what is the problem to that?

Comment: what will I do to `WHERE` clause, c.department column will get String , then the b.end column will get integer , then, do I need to index the department column and the end column too? or department will set as FULLTEXT?

Comment: I add INDEX department on user table, then add INDEX end on document table, the 2 column are my WHERE condition, but sadly nothing change in execution. I don't know what to do now....

Comment: Do another EXPLAIN with the newly created indices and share the result.

Comment: I already updated my SS for EXPLAIN result, please see the update SS.